# DNS for single website not resolving - 'Name or service not known'

Tags: dns, 17.10

Twice now I have had problems connecting to my university's website. All other sites work fine and http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com reports that it's up.

I have tried multiple browsers and pinging the site returns 'Name or service not known'. I think that this is somehow a local DNS resolution problem but I don't know why it's occurring.

FWIW, this time it occurred right after I connected to my VPN which is hosted on that URL.

Comment: what happens when you run `nslookup @8.8.8.8 WEBSITEHERE` but with the website you are actually trying to get to?

Comment: `nslookup: couldn't get address for 'www.northwestern.edu': not found.`

Just running `nslookup www.northwestern.edu` returns `** server can't find www.northwestern.edu: SERVFAIL`

Comment: FWIW, after restarting it works again so something is getting reset during a restart.

Comment: there is a known issue with OpenVPN and NetworkManager/Netplan/resolved/dnsmasq that makes DNS not work properly.  I worked around this by rolling my own recursive resolver on my laptop for non-local addresses.  Which is a very evil approach but 'works'.  This bug has been around since 16.04 but has no resolution as of yet.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the system keeps the old local domain from the VPN connection in the file /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf without deleting it after leaving.
I solved it by editing it manually:
sudo gedit /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf,
after the "search" command remove the now external local network.